# livereload not compiling less file

Tags: html, css, less, livereload, macrabbit-espresso

Im using livereload and using Espresso as my editor, ive linked livereload to my html file, however when i edit my less file it wont load of the functions or styles, but the livereload itself works. When i also try to edit anything on a less file it wont be editable like a css file. everything is in plain text, so i know something is not right in that end.

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="styles.less">
<script src="http://lesscss.googlecode.com/files/less-1.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

Everytime i put stylesheet/less the file just works with html, so its with no style.

Comment: This is just answering your last sentence, but LESS syntax highlighting doesn't work out of the box in Espresso. You need to download a .sugar extension to make this work, or follow this -> http://zurb.com/forrst/posts/Making_Espresso_syntax_highlight_SASS_SCSS-gxI guide

Comment: One of the steps asks me to find a folder called sugars, but i dont have that folder..

Comment: Right. Click the application -> Show contents -> Contents -> SharedSupport -> Plugins -> CSS.espressoplugin (rightclick, show package) -> edit languages.xml with another text editor and add the less extension.

Comment: And have you added this sentences in your head? <script> less = { env: "development", async: false, fileAsync: true }; </script>

Comment: Thank you so much that has worked and now my less file has the right language settings. now i have the problem of my less file not changing anything to my page.

Comment: The less file wont work now, ive linked it to my html, so im back to square one.

Comment: It's quite hard for us to understand what's not working. Could you please elaborate with an example?

Comment: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Coming Soon</title>
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="author" content="" />

<!--mobile specific meta-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>

<!-- css goes here -->
<link rel="stylesheet/css" href="styles.less">
<script src="http://lesscss.googlecode.com/files/less-1.1.3.min.js"></script>

<script> less = { env: "development", async: false, fileAsync: true }; </script>
 and i added the code you said.

Comment: Thats my html code, the less file is linked and is in the right folders, im not sure why its not working also when i try to save the less file it gives me errors saying i need to put closing tags when i already have..

Answer (score 1):

You are linking to http://lesscss.googlecode.com/files/less-1.1.3.min.js

But perhaps you should check to which recourses you are linking before doing so ;)

It's a page that doesn't exist (and if it would exist, it would be very outdated.)

Instead; link to
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.5.1/less.min.js and get more info here http://lesscss.org

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing `stylesheet/less` to `stylesheet/css`?

```
 <link rel="stylesheet/css" href="styles.less">
 <script src="http://lesscss.googlecode.com/files/less-1.1.3.min.js"></script>
```